# How to delete build-in attachment in MS outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have got a lot of emails with build-in attachment (rich-text emails). It is impossible to delete email's attachment by pressing delete button. How to delete the attachment from the email?
[image]

Comment: And if you just click on the attachment with mouse and then  press the Delete key on your keyboard?

Comment: A simple workaround would be to select reply-all to the email, then delete the original sender (and any third parties) from the address list.  This will resend it to you and the default behavior on replies is to exclude attachments.  After you receive it, you can delete the original message.

Comment: fixer1234 such a tricky way)